# How to apply audio effects in iOS

Tags: ios, audiokit, avaudioengine

I use AVPlayer to play audio(streaming or local file). For this audio I want to apply some effects - boost volume, skip silence, reduce noise, change speed(in 0.1 intervals).

I did same thing in android by creating own player, decoding different audio formats into pcm data and then using some c libraries to modify it. It was quite complicated.

Is it possible to do with AVPlayer or how can I do that? Something like modifying audio already decoded by AVPlayer. Is there some ios api ([AVAudioEngine](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudioengine)?) or frameworks ([audioKit](https://audiokit.io/)?) which can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: You can do manipulations in pcm data and create audio files. Please check AVAssetWriter, AVAssetReader classes for this purposes.

Comment: easier way to use audikit framework

Comment: Does it mean I can still use AVPlayer and just inject it and modify audio?

Comment: Is streaming a hard requirement? This is fairly easy to do with the built in effects and a local file.

Comment: yep, streaming is requirement.

Comment: This question is two parts, getting pcm data from a stream, and playing pcm data through effects. I would consider closing this question and opening another, or maybe just editing this question, asking how to get PCM data from a stream first.

Comment: I guess pcm data are probably already there in avplayer. Isn't it only possible to manipulate them?

Answer (score 2):

IMHO the best solution is to use https://github.com/audiokit/AudioKit as it is well maintained and supports most of the requirements you listed.

Another approach is to import the C library you used in the Android project and have a wrapper around it so it can easily used in ObjectiveC/Swift. With this approach you will have less code to maintain and you guarantee similar results between the two platforms. Do you care to share more about this code ?